# Utility to test if application is live in App Store

Tags: software-rec, itunes, iphone

I'm looking for a utility that can tell me if my applications are live in the app store. I can't ping the address, because it's a itms:// and I know there must be a better way that refreshing the page and opening iTunes over and over.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Mac, or preferably iPhone or Web -- I thought it was implied since you can't do iPhone dev on a PC

Comment: iPhone or web based would be [off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq) on this site, though. I asked because you can always check from a PC, even if developed on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Based:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[APP NAME]/id[ID NUMBER]

EX:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/words-with-friends-free/id321916506